# Different Subject Structure

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I saw the sentence below in a scientific book.

> **Also found in this book** are various strategies to assess patient health factors...

I couldn't understand the "Also found in this book" part. What kind of structure it is?

Comment: I think you have misquoted: it should be "Also **found in** this book ...". Google says this passage occurs in Samdani, Amer et al., *Neuromuscular Spine Deformity*, 2018

Comment: Yes, you're right! But I still don't understand.

Comment: @StoneyBonhiatus How did you get the book name? I mean that sentence could occur in tens of books. Also I copied and pasted the same sentence in Google, but that didn't help very much.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh That was two years ago! but I probably looked in Google Books

Answer (score 2):

"Also" - conjunctive adverb, connects the idea of the previous sentence, (i.e. "In this book are ideas about potatoes. Also found in this book are potato recipes.")

"found in this book" - adjective phrase, used in this context to describe the subject of the verb "to be"

"are" - present tense, third person, plural conjugation of the verb "to be"

"various strategies to assess patient health factors" - subject phrase, where "strategies" is the specific noun in question and the other specify the kind of strategies

The meaning of the sentence, then, is that: [In addition to any previous sentences about the matter], [various strategies to assess patient health factors] [are] [in the contents of this book].

Answer (score 1):

This is a (somewhat literary) use of inversion, to bring the topic to the prominent position at the front.

A more normal, neutral, word order would be

> Various strategies to assess patient health factors are also found in this book